# I need help with this question about a graph that has a log in it and the points where it crosses the axes

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

##### Prompt:

> Find the $x$- and $y$-intercepts of the graph of $x = (y+2)\ln(3y+4)$.

##### Given solution:

For $x = 0$, solve $(y+2)\ln(3y+4) = 0$ for $y$:
\begin{align} 
y + 2 &= 0 & \ln(3y + 4) &= 0 \\
y &= -2 & 3y + 4 &= e^0 \\
\rlap{\text{not a solution}}\qquad && 3y + 4 &= 1 \\
&& 3y &= -3 \\
&& y &= -1
\end{align}
So, only $(0, -1)$.

For $y = 0$, evaluate $x = (0 + 2) \ln(3(0) + 4) = 2\ln 4 = 4\ln 2$, so only $(4\ln2, 0)$.

---

##### My question:

Why does $y \neq -2$? Can someone help me in simple terms.

Answer (score 0):

The domain of the natural logarithm function only consist of positive real numbers, but with $y = -2$, the input to the log is $3y + 4 = -2 < 0$.

You can see that [the graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wx54ftibzt) only contains points with $y$-coordinate satisfying $3y + 4 > 0$, i.e., $y > -\tfrac43$.

[image: Graph of equation with asymptote.]